# Is it possibile to call beforeDrawDataPoint function inside afterDataSetFilled? Because i want to get dataset values and fill color

Tags: javascript

This is the function I get the "dataset" values from:

```
function afterDataSetFilled( series, dataSet, icsc )
{

importPackage( Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.attribute.impl );
importPackage( Packages.java.io );
out = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( "c:/temp/datapoints.txt", true ) );

var list = dataSet.getValues();
out.println( "list " + " ------ " + list )
//for (i=0; i<list.length; i++)


out.close();
}
```

Then in the graph, I wanna give colour to that dataset but not in a static way. I wanna make it automatically.

```
Second function is:

function beforeDrawDataPoint(dph, fill, icsc){

importPackage( Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.attribute.impl );
importPackage( Packages.java.io );
out = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( "c:/temp/datapoints.txt", true ) );

var column_name1=[];
var i;

val = dph.getBaseValue();
column_name1.push(val);
for (i=0; i<column_name1.length; i++)
fill.set(i,0,0)
out.close();
}
```

Because I cannot use "fill.set" method in the first function.

Does someone have an idea about it?

In my case, it gives the colour all the same but for each one should be different and should increase one by one then should give automatically different colours.

[image: enter code here]